# Analytical function with Preceding Till a Particular Value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data as below

```
arrayData = [
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:20:11','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:20:15','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:20:19','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:21:11','2021-02-03 10:21:19','Success'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:22:19','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:22:29','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:22:39','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:22:49','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:22:59','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:31:11','2021-02-03 10:31:19','Success'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:31:21','2021-02-03 10:32:19','Success'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 11:32:49','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 11:34:59','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN2','2021-02-03 10:22:49','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN2','2021-02-03 10:22:59','','Fail')
]
root
 |-- event: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Claim_Start: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Claim_End: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Status: string (nullable = true)

+-----+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
|event| PN| SN|        Claim_Start|          Claim_End| Status|
+-----+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:20:11|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:20:15|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:20:19|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:21:11|2021-02-03 10:21:19|Success|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:19|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:29|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:39|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:49|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:59|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:31:11|2021-02-03 10:31:19|Success|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:31:21|2021-02-03 10:32:19|Success|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 11:32:49|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 11:34:59|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN2|2021-02-03 10:22:49|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN2|2021-02-03 10:22:59|                   |   Fail|
+-----+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
```

I do some transformations as below

```
df2 = df.withColumn("event_start_time",f.to_timestamp(df.Claim_Start,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')).withColumn("event_end_time",f.to_timestamp(df.Claim_End,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'))
df2 = df2.drop("Claim_Start").drop("Claim_End")
+-----+---+---+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|event| PN| SN| Status|   event_start_time|     event_end_time|
+-----+---+---+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
|  abc|PN1|SN1|   Fail|2021-02-03 10:20:11|               null|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|   Fail|2021-02-03 10:20:15|               null|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|   Fail|2021-02-03 10:20:19|               null|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|Success|2021-02-03 10:21:11|2021-02-03 10:21:19|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|   Fail|2021-02-03 10:22:19|               null|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|   Fail|2021-02-03 10:22:29|               null|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|   Fail|2021-02-03 10:22:39|               null|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|   Fail|2021-02-03 10:22:49|               null|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|   Fail|2021-02-03 10:22:59|               null|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|Success|2021-02-03 10:31:11|2021-02-03 10:31:19|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|Success|2021-02-03 10:31:21|2021-02-03 10:32:19|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|   Fail|2021-02-03 11:32:49|               null|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|   Fail|2021-02-03 11:34:59|               null|
|  abc|PN1|SN2|   Fail|2021-02-03 10:22:49|               null|
|  abc|PN1|SN2|   Fail|2021-02-03 10:22:59|               null|
+-----+---+---+-------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

The output i require

```
+---+---+-----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+
| PN| SN|event| status|   event_start_time|     event_end_time|          first_try|num_attempts|
+---+---+-----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+
|PN1|SN1|  abc|   Fail|2021-02-03 11:32:49|                   |2021-02-03 11:32:49|           2|
|PN1|SN1|  abc|Success|2021-02-03 10:21:11|2021-02-03 10:21:19|2021-02-03 10:20:11|           4|
|PN1|SN1|  abc|Success|2021-02-03 10:31:11|2021-02-03 10:31:19|2021-02-03 10:22:29|           6|
|PN1|SN1|  abc|Success|2021-02-03 10:31:21|2021-02-03 10:32:19|               null|           1|
|PN1|SN2|  abc|   Fail|2021-02-03 10:22:49|                   |2021-02-03 10:22:49|           2|
+---+---+-----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+
```

Logic for the output,

The Success event happens in the fourth record for SN1 record, and the success was got in was in 4th try, and the first try happened at "2021-02-03 10:20:11". In case of last failures we keep the end date as null and count.

Is there any way i can use the analytical functions and traverse back till the failures i.e. not including the success.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Basically we need a window function, then lag over the Status column to from the groups. Grouping by these and applying the logic you pointed out results in the following code:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

w = Window.partitionBy('PN', 'SN').orderBy('Claim_Start')
df.withColumn('lagged', F.lag('Status').over(w))\
   .withColumn('status_flag', F.when(F.col('lagged') == 'Success', 1).otherwise(0))\
   .withColumn('group', F.sum('status_flag').over(w))\
   .groupBy('PN', 'SN', 'event','group').agg(F.last('Status').alias('status'),
                                             F.when(F.last('Status') == 'Success', F.last('Claim_Start')).otherwise(F.first('Claim_Start')).alias('event_start_time'),
                                             F.last('Claim_End').alias('event_end_time'),
                                             F.when(F.count('Claim_Start') > 1, F.first('Claim_Start')).otherwise(None).alias('first_try'),
                                             F.count('Claim_Start').alias('num_attempts')
                                             ).drop('group').orderBy('PN', 'SN', 'event_end_time').show()
```

results in

```
+---+---+-----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+
| PN| SN|event| status|   event_start_time|     event_end_time|          first_try|num_attempts|
+---+---+-----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+
|PN1|SN1|  abc|   Fail|2021-02-03 11:32:49|                   |2021-02-03 11:32:49|           2|
|PN1|SN1|  abc|Success|2021-02-03 10:21:11|2021-02-03 10:21:19|2021-02-03 10:20:11|           4|
|PN1|SN1|  abc|Success|2021-02-03 10:31:11|2021-02-03 10:31:19|2021-02-03 10:22:19|           6|
|PN1|SN1|  abc|Success|2021-02-03 10:31:21|2021-02-03 10:32:19|               null|           1|
|PN1|SN2|  abc|   Fail|2021-02-03 10:22:49|                   |2021-02-03 10:22:49|           2|
+---+---+-----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+------------+
```