# pyspark window function from current row to a row with specific value

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the data as below and its sorted on the claim_start_date.

```py
arrayData = [
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:20:11','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:20:15','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:20:19','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:21:11','2021-02-03 10:21:19','Success'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:22:19','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:22:29','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:22:39','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:22:49','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:22:59','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:31:11','2021-02-03 10:31:19','Success'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 10:31:21','2021-02-03 10:32:19','Success'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 11:32:49','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN1','2021-02-03 11:34:59','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN2','2021-02-03 10:22:49','','Fail'),
  ('abc','PN1','SN2','2021-02-03 10:22:59','','Fail')
]
root
 |-- event: string (nullable = true)
 |-- PN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- SN: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Claim_Start: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Claim_End: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Status: string (nullable = true)

+-----+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
|event| PN| SN|        Claim_Start|          Claim_End| Status|
+-----+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:20:11|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:20:15|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:20:19|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:21:11|2021-02-03 10:21:19|Success|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:19|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:29|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:39|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:49|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:59|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:31:11|2021-02-03 10:31:19|Success|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:31:21|2021-02-03 10:32:19|Success|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 11:32:49|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 11:34:59|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN2|2021-02-03 10:22:49|                   |   Fail|
|  abc|PN1|SN2|2021-02-03 10:22:59|                   |   Fail|
+-----+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+
```

I want to only traverse back from the current row to the previous successful row, i.e. where the status is success so that I can count the number of retries to make it successful.

Is there any way I can do it.

Comment: Is this the duplication of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67840195/analytical-function-with-preceding-till-a-particular-value/67847817#67847817)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to calculate the number of retries for each successful attempt, you can add a column of the time of next success and group by that column, e.g.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

df2 = df.withColumn(
    'grp', 
    F.first(
        F.when(F.col('Claim_End') != '', F.col('Claim_End')), 
        True
    ).over(
        Window.partitionBy('event', 'PN', 'SN')
              .orderBy('Claim_Start')
              .rowsBetween(0, Window.unboundedFollowing)
    )
).withColumn(
    'cnt', 
    F.count('*').over(Window.partitionBy('event', 'PN', 'SN', 'grp'))
)

df2.show()
+-----+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-------------------+---+
|event| PN| SN|        Claim_Start|          Claim_End| Status|                grp|cnt|
+-----+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-------------------+---+
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:20:11|                   |   Fail|2021-02-03 10:21:19|  4|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:20:15|                   |   Fail|2021-02-03 10:21:19|  4|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:20:19|                   |   Fail|2021-02-03 10:21:19|  4|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:21:11|2021-02-03 10:21:19|Success|2021-02-03 10:21:19|  4|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:19|                   |   Fail|2021-02-03 10:31:19|  6|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:29|                   |   Fail|2021-02-03 10:31:19|  6|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:39|                   |   Fail|2021-02-03 10:31:19|  6|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:49|                   |   Fail|2021-02-03 10:31:19|  6|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:22:59|                   |   Fail|2021-02-03 10:31:19|  6|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:31:11|2021-02-03 10:31:19|Success|2021-02-03 10:31:19|  6|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 10:31:21|2021-02-03 10:32:19|Success|2021-02-03 10:32:19|  1|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 11:32:49|                   |   Fail|               null|  2|
|  abc|PN1|SN1|2021-02-03 11:34:59|                   |   Fail|               null|  2|
|  abc|PN1|SN2|2021-02-03 10:22:49|                   |   Fail|               null|  2|
|  abc|PN1|SN2|2021-02-03 10:22:59|                   |   Fail|               null|  2|
+-----+---+---+-------------------+-------------------+-------+-------------------+---+
```